# How to disconnect from Google authentication after angularfire2/auth signOut?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm building a website using Angular and Firebase.  I'm using Angularfire2 and AngularFireAuth libraries and GoogleAuthProvider (Google) as my authentication provider.

Here is my service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.user = afAuth.authState;
  }

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

When a user 'logs out' of my site, it works, but seems to 'cache' the Google authentication.  So when they attempt to login a second time I run into a few problems:

1. User is not allowed to choose another Google account to login with.
2. User is automatically logged in...which seems like a security problem.  Another user could come to the same shared PC, and login as the previous user and is not required to type in a password to do so.

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a way I can stop angularfire2/auth from caching these credentials?  Is there a way to log users out of Google when they log out of my site?

Comment: Exactly same here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected as they are 2 separate systems and each Auth state is stored separately. Firebase Auth `signOut` signs you out of Firebase. To sign out from Google, you have to go to google and sign out. If this is critical for your app, you can always on Firebase Auth sign out, redirect to the google logout page:

```
auth.signOut().then(() => {
  window.location.assign('https://accounts.google.com/Logout');
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, and agree this is "as designed" but I still believe it's an unfortunate user experience.  I'd prefer an option to let me login using Google credentials, but NOT log me into Google at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, you could do it more discreetly by following the "solution" at this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/PCs8xXV4wxk).
I am using it in my app in case the user is not authorized to access the database, but you can add the iframe anywhere.

logout service:

```
function LogoutService($location){
        this.logOut = function(myAuth){
            myAuth.$signOut().then(() => {

                $location.path("/logout");

            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        };
    };
```

router:

```
.when('/logout', {
            templateUrl : "login/logout.html"
        })
```

logout.html:

```
<div class="container" >

<p >{{logUser.unauthUser}} unauthorized. Try again.</p>

<iframe id="logoutframe" src="https://accounts.google.com/logout" style="display: none"></iframe>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a little late, but I had the same problem and I have resolved this with the next source code:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserLoginService {
    constructor(
        public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
    ) { }

    async signIn() {
        try {
            // The custom parameters for the Google provider is the clue
            const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
            provider.setCustomParameters({
                prompt: 'select_account'
            });
            await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    // other code here
}
```

With this, always that you try to login, it is the same if you only are login in one account, the popup ask you which account must use to login to Firebase, and you will be able to see the typical option to select other google account or add a new one.

It is true that perhaps is not the best solution, but you won't have to to sign out from all google accounts in your computer and avoid other kind of errors like CORS error (when you try to redirect to Google logout url) or if you have some restriction into Firebase by domain, the error when you have some previous Google account signed in.

I hope that with this you can find your solution.